# Pyspark : TypeError: _api() takes 1 positional argument

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I use this code for the pivot on the dataframe :

```
df2 = df.groupBy("id").pivot("status").count("status")
df = df.join(df2, on="id", how='left')
```

But I obtain this error :
***TypeError: _api() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given***

Please, can we help me ??

Comment: could you please confirm whether you got a solution to above problem. Also, could you please share a sample dataset where you attempted above error.

Answer (score 0):

When you would to count aggregated values, you could import spark sql functions:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as spark_sql_functions
```

For example, let's you have next dataframe:

```py
df.show()

+--------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|             country|             name|        subcountry|
+--------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|             Andorra|     les Escaldes|Escaldes-Engordany|
|             Andorra| Andorra la Vella|  Andorra la Vella|
|United Arab Emirates|   Umm al Qaywayn|    Umm al Qaywayn|
|United Arab Emirates|   Ras al-Khaimah|   Raʼs al Khaymah|
|United Arab Emirates|     Khawr Fakkān|      Ash Shāriqah|
|United Arab Emirates|            Dubai|             Dubai|
...
...
```

Use the agg function with spark sql functions:

```py
df_cities = df.groupBy('country', 'subcountry').agg(
  spark_sql_functions.count('name').alias('cities')).groupBy('country').agg(
    spark_sql_functions.count('subcountry').alias('subcountry'),
    spark_sql_functions.sum('cities').alias('cnt')).sort(spark_sql_functions.desc('cnt'))
df_cities.show()
=>
+--------------+----------+----+
|       country|subcountry| cnt|
+--------------+----------+----+
| United States|        51|2699|
|         India|        35|2443|
|        Brazil|        27|1200|
|        Russia|        82|1093|
|       Germany|        16|1055|
|         China|        31| 799|
|         Japan|        47| 736|
|        France|        13| 633|
|         Italy|        20| 571|
...
```

I hope this example be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your `df.groupBy("id").pivot("status").count("status")` this statement gives error as `count` will only accept `self` object itself [Check source code here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.count).

If you want to get rid of error just remove `status` from `count` as below.

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("status").count()
```